# jquery datatables - How to replace excel icon instead of button?

Tags: jquery, css, datatables, tabletools

I want to implement the excel icon instead of a button for excel export option in DataTable. I have placed the table tools reference and trying to implement the export excel sheet.

1. How to use excel icon instead of a button?
2. Are there any possibilities to design the excel sheet header and table format?
3. How to move the export button to the right side of the table?

Please look into [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rwPFx/34/)

```
var oTable = $("#products1").dataTable({
       "aaData": newarray,
       "bProcessing": true,
       "bDeferRender": true,
       "bFilter": false,
       "bRetrieve": true,
       "bPaginate": true,
       "bJQueryUI": true,
       "sPaginationType": "two_button",
      "sDom": '<"H"Tfr>t<"F"ip>',
       "oTableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "../images/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
             "aButtons": [ 
             {
                "sExtends": "xls",
                "sFileName": "*.xls"
             }]
        },
       "bSort": true,
       "aaSorting": [[2, 'asc']],
       "iDisplayLength": 5,
       "aoColumns": [{"sWidth": "135px","sClass": "center","bSortable": true},{
            "sWidth": "145px","sClass": "center","bSortable": true},{
            "sWidth": "20px","sClass": "center","bSortable": false},{
            "sWidth": "145px","sClass": "center","bSortable": false}             
            ],
        "aoColumnDefs": [{ "fnRender": function (o, val) {
            return o.aData[0];
        },
            "sClass": "","aTargets": [0]
    }, {
        "fnRender": function (o, val) {

            return o.aData[1];
        },
            "sClass": "","aTargets": [1]
    }, {
    "fnRender": function (o, val) {

            return o.aData[2];
        },
            "sClass": "Number","aTargets": [2]
    },{
    "fnRender": function (o, val) {

            return o.aData[3];
        },
            "sClass": "Description","aTargets": [3]
    }]

});
```

Answer (score 2):

1.) You can either

a) use jquery ui to put an icon next to the text button like this
    example http://iksela.tumblr.com/post/2727627360/display-tabletools-buttons-as-jqueryui-buttons-with-an

b) extend the plugin and use your own custom button as the documentation describes http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/button_options

2.) No, the Excel button is essentially a "cheat" it is a tab separated file with ".xls" appended. In order todo this, you would need to have your datatables be server-side not client side ("bServerSide": true), and have your excel button as a custom button that runs a server-side script that will query/create the excel with options

Before doc ready

```
TableTools.BUTTONS.download = {
    "sAction": "text",
    "sTag": "default",
    "sFieldBoundary": "",
    "sFieldSeperator": "\t",
    "sNewLine": "<br>",
    "sToolTip": "",
    "sButtonClass": "DTTT_button_text",
    "sButtonClassHover": "DTTT_button_text_hover",
    "sButtonText": "Download",
    "mColumns": "all",
    "bHeader": true,
    "bFooter": true,
    "sDiv": "",
    "fnMouseover": null,
    "fnMouseout": null,
    "sExtraData":[],
    "fnClick": function( nButton, oConfig ) {
    var oParams = this.s.dt.oApi._fnAjaxParameters( this.s.dt );
      //oParams = oParams.concat(oConfig.aExtraData);
      oParams.push({name: "bShowInactive", value: $("#bShowInactive").is(":checked") });    

    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.style.height = "0px";
    iframe.style.width = "0px";
    iframe.src = oConfig.sUrl+"?"+$.param(oParams);
    document.body.appendChild( iframe );
    },
    "fnSelect": null,
    "fnComplete": null,
    "fnInit": null
};
```

in datatables function

```
"oTableTools": {
          "aButtons": [ {
            "sExtends": "download",
            "sButtonText": "Download XLS",
            "sUrl": "index.cfm/reports:interact/downloadXLS",
            "sExtraData":[], //for static var passing
            "fnInit":   function(node){formatTableToolsButton(node, 'ui-icon-document');}
          }]
      }
```

Then the coldfusion url uses SpreadsheetFormatRow to bold center the excel columns

3.) you can change your styles using css something like this should get you started

```
div.DTTT_container {
position: relative;
float: right;
margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```